# Trying to post username and password to restful API using resttemplate but getting error.

Tags: spring-mvc, resttemplate

I  am getting error when i try to run the code as Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 407 Proxy Authentication Required.

Controller class:

```
package com.concretepage.controller;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.concretepage.bean.Quote;

@Controller
public class LoginController {


    @RequestMapping(value="login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(){
        System.setProperty("proxyHost", "proxy1.wipro.com"); 
        System.setProperty("proxyPort", "8080");
        return "redirect:pages/login.jsp";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="pages/userCheck", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String userCheck(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String name=request.getParameter("name");
        String pwd=request.getParameter("pwd");
        if("concretepage".equalsIgnoreCase(name)&&"concretepage".equalsIgnoreCase(pwd)){

            model.addAttribute("message", "Successfully logged in.");
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters =restTemplate.getMessageConverters();
            MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter map =new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter();
            messageConverters.add(map);
            restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

            MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
            params.add("userName", name);
            params.add("passWord", pwd);
            Quote result = restTemplate.postForObject( "http://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random", params, Quote.class) ;
            System.out.println("username="+result.getValue().getUserName());

            /*Quote quote = restTemplate.getForObject("http://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random", Quote.class);
            System.out.println(quote.getType());*/


        }else{
            model.addAttribute("message", "Username or password is wrong.");
        }
        return "redirect:success.jsp";
    }

}

qoute bean class:
package com.concretepage.bean;

import com.concretepage.bean.Value;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Quote {

    private String type;
    private Value value;

    public Quote() {
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Value getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Value value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Quote{" +
                "type='" + type + '\'' +
                ", value=" + value +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Is http://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random also managed by you? You are sure that name and password are to be sent via params?

Comment: No gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random is not managed by me but i am sending the name and password via resttemplate post to gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random.I am new to this i have jst written what i understood from online tutorials.It might be wrong.